# Data Adapter does not update all rows updated

Tags: vb.net

So long story short I have a dgv that gets data from a mysql database and I can make changes to the data in the grid and save back to the table, no problem except this: Changes made by the user on the dgv are not done directly (or manually) on the dgv, rather the user clicks plus or minus buttons and I pragmatically increase or decrease the number in a certain field called Quantity which is actually the only field that can be updated.

Now when I update my adapte command (...da.Update(ds, "salesDet")), the row I changed last does not get updated unless I manually leave that row to another row before pressing the update button. So for instance if I have 3 rows in the dgv and I select row 2 which has a quantity of 1, then I press the plus button, the quantity changes to 2. Then if I immediately press my update button while still on row 2, it will not get updated to my database. It will only work if prior to pressing the update button I leave row 2 to say row 1 or 3. Kind of like because I'm changing the numbers programmatically and not manually, I need to leave the edited row for an "after-update" commitment of the new values to fire? Don't know if I'm making sense but I'm really lost

I have tried dgv.EndEdit(), dgv.RefreshEdit(), dgv.Refresh() before updating but none of that works.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Sounds like the current row hasn't been validated yet, so your change has not taken effect.  A clumsy hacky way of getting round this might be to set dgv.CurrentRow to nothing at the start of your Update method to force validation.  Someone will probably be along with a more elegant solution though.

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom you call it clumsy I call it genius. It worked. I used the CurrentCell(Index of first visible column) though because CurrentRow is read only. Thanks a million.

Comment: Will post as an actual answer then.  It's still not the ideal solution, but if it works it works.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the current row hasn't been validated yet, so your change has not taken effect. A clumsy hacky way of getting round this might be to set dgv.CurrentRow to nothing at the start of your Update method to force validation.